# Arduino - stopping the loop of readString.indexOf (+Blinking LED loop break)

Tags: arduino, blink

**My situation**
I'm using shift registers to control 72 LEDs individal.
Each LED can be activated via a specific request. It is easy to set the LED to HIGH, but the LED should blink. Making the LED blink via "for" is not a problem.
I managed to make the LED blinking, once it it blinking it does not stop when a new request comes in. The LED should blink only till a new request arrives.

**My problem** is if during the blinking peroid (in the example 3 times) I can not stop it. If I'm sending a new `if(readString.indexOf("?button1onA2") > 0)` for example for an other LED (?button1onA2) the request will be ignored as long as the LED from the request before is still blinking.

**My target** is to make the LED blink, **but stop** when a new request via 'readstring' arrives.

**My Question:**

- is there a better way to make the LED flashing in a loop other then using 
  `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` ?
- one I'm in the loop how can I **break** it and move on to the next LED?

**My code**

`if (readString.indexOf("?button1onA1") > 0)`
In this case the LED with the sensor ID 4 should blink.

```
      if (readString.indexOf("?button1onA1") > 0) {

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
          shifter.setPin(4, HIGH);
          shifter.write();
          delay(200);
          shifter.setPin(4, LOW);
          shifter.write();
          delay(200);

        }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on the arduino.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use non blocking delays (e.g., [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)).
A good way is also using state machine (or many of them).

But in theory, you can just store bitmasks for the LEDs, that should blink, and blink them all synchronously (with non blocking delays).

Comment: thanks,
I have added it into the code, but no blinking

          if (readString.indexOf("?wall01_01") > 0) {

            unsigned long now = millis();
            if (now - lastTime >= PERIOD) // this will be true every PERIOD milliseconds
            {
              lastTime = now;
              if (ledState == LOW)
              {
                ledState = HIGH;
              }
              else
              {
                ledState = LOW;
              }
              shifter.setPin(1, ledState);
              shifter.write();
            }

          }

Comment: @Sebastian, please update the source code and add description on your question instead of a comment.